# How to select data from columns that match a criteria?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Hi i have a table in mysql database which has columns like UI_12-Apr-2016,DA_12-Apr-2016.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| DA_12-Apr-2016  | UI_13-Apr-2016 | UI_12-Apr-2016 | DA_13-Apr-2016 | 
|---------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                                    |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How do i fetch data from the table whose columns have 12-Apr-2016 in it. Is there any way to select data according to the criteria. I know i can run this query:-

```
SELECT UI_12-Apr-2016,DA_12-Apr-2016 from table;
```

but the date and the code before it can be anything. I want to create a dynamic query to fetch data from the columns that match the date criteria.

I would be highly grateful if anyone can please provide a solution to do it.

Comment: Do you mean column names, or column data?

Comment: @jarlh I want to fetch the data from the columns that have 12-Apr-2016

Comment: Hope you mean column name contains `12-Apr-2016` right?

Comment: Different columns, depending on date, seems a bit odd. I'd have a date column instead, and more rows for data!

Comment: @Arulkumar Yes some column contains 12-Apr-2016, I want to select data from those which has 12-Apr-2016

Comment: `SELECT UI_12-Apr-2016,DA_12-Apr-2016 from table;` that translates to `SELECT UI_12 MINUS Apr MINUS 2016,DA_12 MINUS Apr MINU 2016 from table`, did you know that? MySQL thinks you want to do math. You need to wrap that in ticks `\``

Answer (score 3):

This may help:

```
select COLUMN_name
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME='Table1' and column_name like "%12-Apr-2016%";
```

in the above query, we can search for column names from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS table(which holds data related to table specified).

Output of above query should:

```
UI_12-Apr-2016
DA_12-Apr-2016
```

The **result of above query is a list of columns with the pattern given**(%12-Apr-2016%). You may **save this result in a list and use it to fetch data** accordingly from the table.

**There is no direct method or query to do the same.**

Comment: This will only give column names i want to fetch the data as well from the columns

Comment: you have to use list or arrays in php to store result of the query(given above) and write another query to fetch data from the table.

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%13-Apr-2016%';
```

?

Update: you should look into information_schema database:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME from `COLUMNS` where `TABLE_NAME` = 'table_name' AND `COLUMN_NAME` LIKE '%12-Apr-2016%';
```

Simple PHP example script could be:

```
$table_name = 'table_name';
$col_pattern = '12-Apr-2016';

$mysqli = new mysqli($config['host'], $config['user'], $config['password'], $config['dbname']);
$sql1 = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME from `COLUMNS` where `TABLE_NAME` = '{$table_name}' AND `COLUMN_NAME` LIKE '%{$col_pattern}%'";
$res1 = $mysqli->query($sql1);
$acol = array();
while ($r1 = $res1->fetch_assoc()) {
    $acol[] = $r1['COLUMN_NAME'];
}
if (!empty($acol)) {
    $sql2 = 'SELECT ' . implode(', ', $acol) . ' FROM ' . $table_name;
    $res2 = $mysqli->query($sql2);
    while ($r2 = $res2->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo var_export($r2, 1) . PHP_EOL;
    }   
}
```

Comment: This is not what the OP needs. He is looking to wildcard search column names, not the data within the columns.

Comment: I want to fetch the data of those particular coumns in a table in php, information_schema will only give column names

Comment: Make 2 SQL queries. 1 - Get column names. 2 - Get the data from such columns.

Comment: @Taras Can you please provide a way to do that

Comment: @Taras Thank you for providing the solution, the method you gave stores column names in array but gives error on second while loop, Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can create a new table `tbl_column` with one column `column_name` include all your columns~
SELECT * FROM `tbl_column` WHERE column_name LIKE '%12-Apr-2016%';
then you can use the query result to generate a new dynamic sql~

Answer (score 1):

It is **not possible** to dynamically come up with names of columns since MySQL does not have an eval() function. Since you are using PHP, it is preferable to construct the query from your application in order to achieve this.

If you really insist for a solution using MySQL, there is one using [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) that is not too hard to come up with as follows:

```
set @table='your_table_name';

select group_concat(column_name) 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name='your_table_name' 
and column_name like '%12_Apr_2016' 
into @colnames;

set @construct= CONCAT('SELECT ', @colnames, ' FROM ', @table);
prepare query from @construct;
execute query;
```

#### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37c815/2) for reference.

But overall, having columns named using dynamically generated DDL is not the best schema modeling practice.

Comment: I just want to fetch data from columns which have 12-Apr-2016, the date may vary

Comment: You still haven't verified clearly if your column names are what needs to match your pattern or the data within it. I don't recommend my solution but only offer it to demonstrate that it is possible. You can vary what goes into the `like ` clause in the `select` part of this solution to match whatever pattern you want to match against.

Comment: I added a fiddle to the solution to demonstrate how this hack works.

Comment: How can i use the above method in php

Answer (score 1):

You must put together your SQL statement dynamically. E.g. the following statement uses the Oracle view `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` to produce a `select column_name from table_name` statement for every column that contains `12-Apr-2016`:

```
SELECT 'SELECT ' || COLUMN_NAME || ' FROM ' || TABLE_NAME || ';'
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE'
AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%12-Apr-2016%'
```

This may not be exactly what you want, however, this illustrates the general idea.

Comment: This only creates a query which can be done without all the hassle from within the application itself. It is not possible to execute the query generated dynamically which I believe the OP is looking for.